# MySQL Why I Cannot Delet A Row on Self Referecing Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE Employee 
(SSN  INT  NOT  NULL,
Name    VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
Supervisor   INT,
DNo   INT,
PRIMARY   KEY(SSN),
FOREIGN    KEY(Supervisor)   
REFERENCES   Employee(SSN),
FOREIGN   KEY(DNo) 
REFERENCES Department(DNumber)
ON DELETE  SET NULL
ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

Table is currently;

```
SSN Name  Supervisor   DNo
12  Jack  NULL         NULL
14  Cath  12           6
18  Cath  12           NULL
```

and query:

```
DELETE FROM Employee WHERE SSN = 12;
```

In MySQL, it gives the error:

```
Error Code:1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row:a foreign key constraint fails...
```

I do not ask a solution to delete. I want an explanation why cannot delete this tuple.

Comment: You still have two rows that reference the one you are trying to delete and the FK is defined without any options so it's "on delete restrict"

Comment: In Mysql Workbench, I explicitly choose NO ACTION for both delete and update situations because it is the default is sql as far as I learnt from school.

Comment: `NO ACTION` means "do nothing" so nothing will be set to null or deleted. Which in turn means the two other rows will still reference the row you try to delete. `NO ACTION` does not mean the DML statement that violates the FK will not be executed. (`NO ACTION` is essentially the same as `RESTRICT` - I have never understood why there are two options that do the same thing).

Answer (score 1):

Your `ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE` only applies to the `DNo` foreign key, not to the `Supervisor` foreign key.

If no foreign key options are provided, the [foreign key defaults to `restrict`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html), which fails the operation.

If you don't want that, provide the option you want, e.g.

```
FOREIGN KEY(Supervisor) REFERENCES Employee(SSN) ON DELETE SET NULL
```